# Java Calendar in Android may be bug

Tags: java, android, calendar

The following code cannot pass the assertion under the Android emulator:

```
TimeZone timezone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("Hongkong");
Locale locale = new Locale("zh", "HK"); 
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(timezone, locale);

calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, 1979);
calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, 4);        
calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 13);            
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 4);  
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);      
calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);        

DateFormat df = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(DateFormat.LONG, DateFormat.LONG, locale);
df.setTimeZone(timezone);
String sDate = df.format(calendar.getTime());

int debug = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
Assert.assertEquals("Error datetime: " + sDate, 4, debug);
```

And I found that, if change the DAY_OF_MONTH to 12, the error is gone:
    calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 12);

Note that this problem is not exists on JUnit test. (without Android)

Finally, this problem seems may not be exists on Android real machine.

Any comments?

Comment: What makes you think that "Hongkong" is a valid time zone ID?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is to do with the DST transition on May 13th 1979, but I don't have time to investigate right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe, it's because of this transition:

> Hong Kong adopted daylight saving measures in 1941. However, in the 1970s, the government found these measures unnecessary as Hong Kong is at a relatively low latitude. **The practice was eliminated in 1979**.

Here is the DST change which happened on 13th May 1979.

> **Sunday, May 13, 1979**   3:29:59 AM  No  UTC+8h  HKT
>
> **3:30:00 AM → 4:30:00 AM +1h**   UTC+9h  HKST    DST starts
>
> Sunday, October 21, 1979   3:29:59 AM  +1h UTC+9h  HKST

Since DST for Hong Kong went ON and OFF and finally OFF, it may be the root cause of the issue.

Comment: Thank you very much.

So how can I off the daylight saving effect from Java Calendar operation?